# Trying to get DXperience under Linux: I get "Windows Installer 3" required when installing .NET 2.0 under wine in SLED

Tags: .net, cross-platform, suse, dxperience

I want to try out `DXperience` component suite on Linux (Suse Linux enterprise desktop). Since it relies heavily on the PInvoke calls, Mono would not work out here.

Some people were able to get this running by installing .NET 2.0 under wine on Linux.

I've tried to do this with the winetricks and manually. Every time .NET 2.0 install on SLED hits the "Installer 3 requirement" with the latest wine.

Installing the MSI3 itself fails due to the absence of the crypto services.

It is possible to avoid this requirement by installing .NET 2.0 in Win98 mode, but the installation process breaks before the end.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you could possibly install .Net 2.0 in linux. Even if you could by using some hacks, you would probably ended up with half broken framework.

Well, I googled and found this page [Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries), I suppose you can use pinvoke in mono, and have wine intepret that properly. This way it's much proven to work and you can probably get more help from the community, rather than installing .Net 2.0 in linux.

Comment: I'm not worried about the possibility of doing it, since it is possible to do that in 3 command lines (winetricks) and it seems to work for the majority of people (Gold status on Wine AppDb).

Comment: But you mentioned "Since it relies heavily on the PInvoke calls, Mono would not work out here.". I did point out that it's possible to do pinvoke in mono, though I've not tested it personally.